# Фильтр Винера и FFTW

Tags: fft, qt, c++

Идея реализовать фильтр Винера для восстановления изображений.
[Формула здесь.](http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/9/f/2/9f2f68034fd0671292fda1eeedee2793.png)
На сколько понимаю, то необходимо сделать дискретное преобразование фурье ядра и самого изображения, которое необходимо восстановать, а затем уже с ними работать.
Ниже код, как я думаю, который должен реализовать DFT для входного изображения.
Однако полученные результаты не совпадают с примерами из сети.
Должно было получиться [link text](http://savepic.ru/3993467.gif), а получилось [link text](http://savepic.ru/3982203m.jpg).

```
//fftw_complex *inputImageFFT;     
//fftw_complex *outputImageFFT;
//fftw_plan plan;  
int N;
width = this->inImg.width();
height = this->inImg.height();
N=width*height;

inputImageFFT = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex)*N);
outputImageFFT = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex)*N);
plan = fftw_plan_dft_2d(width,height,inputImageFFT,outputImageFFT,
FFTW_FORWARD,FFTW_ESTIMATE);

   for (int i = 0, k = 0; i < height; i++)
   {
       for (int j = 0; j < width; j++, k++)
       {
           inputImageFFT[k][0] = (uint)inImg.pixel(j,i);
           inputImageFFT[k][1] =  0.0;
        }

   }

   fftw_execute(plan);

   float max=0;
   float mag=0;
   for (int i = 1, k = 1; i < height; i++)
   {
       for (int j = 1; j < width; j++, k++)
       {
            mag = qSqrt(qPow(outputImageFFT[k][0],2) + pow(outputImageFFT[k][1],2));
            if (max < mag)
            max = mag;
       }

  }

   outImg = new QImage(width,height, QImage::Format_RGB32);

   for (int i = 0, k = 0; i < height; i++)
   {
       for (int j = 0; j < width; j++, k++)
       {
           float mag = sqrt(pow(outputImageFFT[k][0],2) + pow(outputImageFFT[k][1],2));
           mag = 255*(mag/max);
           outImg->setPixel(j,i,qRgb(mag,mag,mag));
       }
   }
//вывод outImg
```

Подскажите, в том ли направлении реализации фильтра я двигаюсь и в какую сторону рыть?

Comment: Сам недавно начал разбираться с fftw... Вроде с кодом всё норм.

Answer (score 1):

Есть отличный набор статей по теме на хабре:

[Восстановление расфокусированных и смазанных изображений](http://habrahabr.ru/post/136853/) и
[Восстановление расфокусированных и смазанных изображений. Практика](http://habrahabr.ru/post/147828/)  и есть ещё одна из серии, в статье найдёте ссылку.

Там всё расписано как и что делать. В качестве примера приводится программа, написанная автором под названием [smart deblur](https://github.com/Y-Vladimir/SmartDeblur).

Comment: Да, объяснение в статьях целостное (видно, что человек постарался на славу), но smart deblur программа больше для тестирования самих фильтров, а не в плане примера реализации. Т. к. программа написана с максимальной оптимизацией. Основной вопрос, который я не могу решить, с чем связано то, что у меня не "совпадает", причем весьма сильно, фурье преобразования тестовой картинки. В какую сторону копать.. Или я не правильно работаю с FFTW и как следствие  получаю совсем не фурье образ или же проблема в самой логике.